# No projects displaying in Eclipse Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). For about a week, everything keeps disappearing from Project explorer, Navigator, and Package Explorer. In Project Explorer, if I click on the menu and then Deselect Working Set, the list comes back, but a couple hours later it will disappear again.

I saw a few solutions that say to go to File->Import->General->From Existing Project and import the project again, but I can't do that because it says the projects are already imported, I just can't see them. I was also trying to avoid creating a new workspace because then I lose all my settings and perspective layouts.

Comment: The 'Deselect Working Set' menu item only becomes selectable if there is actually a working set active. So it sounds like somehow you are managing to activate a single, empty, working set (this is different from the Top Level Elements' option.

Comment: A couple of hours ago, I went to "Select Working Set..." and changed the option to "No Working Sets". This brought the list back and so far it hasn't disappeared again. So, that may have fixed it, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you accidentally set the "Top Level Elements" to be Working Sets instead of projects. If you do not have any Working Sets, the view will be empty.

If you click the down arrow on the right of the four buttons, you'll have the option to select "Top Level Elements" > "Projects".

[image]